# PowerEdge 1800 1-3-2 beep fault

Tags: dell-poweredge

I had this fault arise, after checking the memory and as far as i can tell appears to be OK, I followed the Dell recommendation and replaced the main board, but the fault still appears?  any help would be greatfuly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1-3-2 Beep error indicates no memory installed.  [Dell 1800 Info](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe1800/en/it/r2053c20.htm) I assume you have memory so possibly the main board is an issue or RAM.  Have you tried removing all RAM and adding back in?

Was the replacement board a new/refurb Dell part?